# Civicrm Membership Type in webforms

Tags: webforms, civicrm

I am using the webform_civicrm module. It is not having the option to link the membership type to webforms.
How can I link membership type to webforms?

Answer (score 6):

Support for memberships was just added in version 4 of Webform-CiviCRM integration. If you upgrade to that version then membership types will become available.